# How should I go about connecting a switch's ground wire to this apparent grouping of ground wires?

Tags: grounding, dimmer-switch

We have an old dimmer switch in a two-switch box (next to a regular light bulb) (in California). The old dimmer switch's button no longer works right, so we wanted to replace it with a new one. We got a Lutron switch to replace it, and I looked over the instructions, but when I saw the wiring of the old switch it made me hesitate. The main thing I'm concerned about is the ground wire.

From the old dimmer switch, there is a capped off (unused) black wire and it has a red wire and a black wire connected to white wires in the box. This is a little different from the new dimmer switch which just has two black wires (besides the ground wire), but as far as I know I would connect the two black wires to those two white wires. Feel free to comment if that is right or wrong.

But for the ground wire, what I expected was that the box would have a green or copper wire coming out of the box with the old dimmer switch's ground wire connected to it. Rather, the old dimmer switch's green ground wire looks to be almost grabbed onto by a group of wires like fingers.

So what should I do? Is this normal wiring? Is it safe? Should I mimic it with the new switch? Should I leave it to an electrician? Are there particular instructions that I should follow, or would I need any special tools to open/close the fingers around the ground wire if I were to do the same thing for the new dimmer switch?

As it is, I pushed everything back in the box and screwed it back in (I hadn't disconnected any of the wires). Thank you.

[image: wiring of dimmer switch]
[image: image of ground wiring connection]

Comment: Note that those aren't really white wires, they're *painted* wires, big difference :)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Is there anything I should know about that? Do I connect the two black wires from the dimmer switch to the two painted white wires? Is there anything that being painted white would indicate compared to how I see other instructions that have red and black wires in the box?

Comment: When you see paint slopped all over the wires in a box like that, it has no significance other than "a sloppy painter or drywaller was here".  I'd carefully scrape the paint off the wires you want to hook up to the switch so that you can verify their wire colors

Comment: Black or colored paint is allowed re-mark a white wire for use as a hot.  That is the only re-marking allowed.  Nothing can be re-marked to be neutral.

Answer (score 2):

The old dimmer is not properly connected to ground (an attempt was made, but it's not good workmanship...)

The grounding wires are crimped (which seems to be a popular method at some places and times for grounding wires, I assume because someone felt it saved 3 seconds per box or something) but the old dimmer grounding wire is not in the crimp, it's just jammed between the crimped wires.

If one or more of the grounding wires that are in the crimp stick out far enough on the other side of it you can use a wire-nut to properly connect your new dimmer's grounding wire. Can't see if that's the case since they appear to be behind the other switch in your pictures.

If not, you can cut off the crimp and use a wire nut to connect all the grounding wires and your new dimmer grounding wire.

Comment: Thanks. When you say if it sticks out far enough on the other side, wouldn’t they all just connect to something in the box without any accessible end in that direction? Maybe one of the wires that is “grabbing” onto the old switch’s grounding wire could be connected via a wire nut? Or if I were to connect them all to the new ground wire with a wire nut, wouldn’t I need a much bigger wire nut? (Why is there more than one wire in that group anyway?)

Comment: Also, to clarify, is that group of wires the correct grounding wire to use? Since it looks strange and this is new territory for me, I want to be able to know that I would be doing it right and not anything unsafe.

Comment: I can't tell from your picture which way they actually run - I'm assuming the bit where the old dimmer ground is stuffed in is about where there's a bend towards the back of the box. If it's the free end instead, then it looks like you don't have room for a nut there. That group has all the grounding wires from all the cables connected to this box, which is how grounding happens for everything connected to those cables. A wire nut will have to be an appropriate size for the number and size of wires.

Comment: Should I try to pull it all out of the box to see? Should I expect that on the other side of the crimp that there’s a wire with a free end not connected to anything, and if there is one like that it would be the proper wire to secure the new dimmer switch’s grounding wire to with the nut? If the crimp is holding all the grounding wires together, I certainly wouldn’t want to cut that off right?

Comment: Also, should I assume that the original installer of the old dimmer switch stuffed the ground wire where the grounds were crimped, when they could and should have found a lose wire on the other end of the crimp to use for the dimmer?

Comment: *Expect nothing*, and see **what you actually have.** If there is either a wire with a free end or a wire connected to the other switch's grounding screw, you can connect to those. There might be no wire with a free end since old switches didn't have grounding screws - in which case you would be better served to cut the crimp and replace it with a wire nut so you can connect your modern switch(es) to ground correctly.

Comment: Confused re if there is a wire connected to the other switch’s grounding screw, how could I connect it to that if it’s already being used there? And then otherwise you’re saying my options are, there is either a free wire on the other side of that crimp which I should use, **or** I would need to get a larger wire nut and connect the new dimmer’s ground wire with the whole lot. (But either way those are for sure usable ground wires?) Also side question, but is there any safety concern with just leaving things as they’ve been (taking no action to replace the dimmer and leaving the old wiring)?

Comment: I watched this about grounding wires to try to get a better understanding: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sl88dZn1APA So does it seem like where they are crimped is the equivalent to where the wire nut was used in the video? And then perhaps there is a free tail end running off toward the right which I would then use to connect to the new dimmer's ground? Also when I try to get access to it and see what the actual situation is, is there a risk of a ground wire being moved wrongly and bumping it into anything in that box like a terminal which would cause any problems; any precautions to take?

Comment: Also, sorry for going on, but if we try to pull out the group of crimped wires to see what is on the other side and the old dimmer's ground wire comes out but we're not ready to immediately install a new switch or cut off the old crimp to combine them with a wire nut (whether because we don't have a large enough wire nut on hand or for lack of confidence going off book like this) would there be a safest course of action on our part, such as pushing the ground wire back into the group as before or whether removing the old switch entirely and doing something to cap off the old wires in any way?

Comment: @AL I'd just make sure you have some good sized wire-nuts (or 8 or 12 port push-in connectors for that matter) on hand before you start, you really aren't going "off book" at all, more cleaning up the "off book" thing the last bloke did and making it actually yanno, meet Code

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Any guides you'd recommend for me to look at so that a layman like me, who was just expecting to need to follow the dimmer's installation instructions, would know what I'm doing when it comes to using the wire nuts or push in connectors to fix up the wiring (if needed, that is; hopefully there will be a loose end from the ground wires I can use).

Comment: @AL -- basically, read the instructions on the connector you're using to make sure that you aren't trying to stuff too many wires into it, and if you're using a wirenut, make sure to crank it down *hard*

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Okay thanks. What about any good places to learn about the basics of and common mistakes in the wiring of these sorts of boxes, so that I'd be able to tell if something is wrong when I've got the box open rather than leave the fuse off posting another question? I've seen some YouTube videos, and from that and the explanations here it sounds pretty straightforward, but I also know that wiring something wrong can be catastrophic and that I have no background in this and might not know what I don't know (sorry if I'm sounding overly cautious).

Comment: @AL -- pick up a book on basic house wiring from your local library I reckon

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Thanks